# Error al intentar probar Python en Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Estaba haciendo una línea de código y cuando usé la opción del **ctrl+b** para probarlo directamente en el Sublime Text, pero cuando intenté hacerlo me salió este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código era un simple "hola mundo".

```py
print("hola mundo")
```

Espero que puedan ayudarme, y gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Hiciste esto primero ?? Tools->Build System->Python ??

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! al parecer no ejecutaste nada...

Comment: @Excorpion sí, eso hice.

Comment: No te aparece ningún error diferente tampoco ??? El archivo se guardo correctamente como .py antes de ejecutarlo y todo ? @Anonymus

Comment: Nunca lo guardé, sólo hice el código y usé el ctrl+b.

Comment: Debes guardarlo antes de ejecutarlo bro... Guardalo, haz lo de tools, y las posteriores usa el ctrl+b. Lo de tools construye el ambiente, luego solo lo corres.

Comment: Oh, bien.
Gracias.

Comment: He dejado la "solución" al problema, si es la solución, recuerda marcarla por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Agrego la respuesta para cerrar el POST.

El OP cometió el error de **NO GUARDAR EL ARCHIVO .py**
Estaba intentando ejecutar python, sin que existiera un archivo para ejecutar.

Siempre deben seguir estos pasos en el caso descrito.

> 1. Crear el código a ejecutar
> 2. Guardarlo con el formato correcto (.py)
> 3. En Sublime, con el archivo ya existente, construir el sistema en la sección 
>    **TOOLS->Build System ->Python**
> 4. Una vez hecho estos pasos y ejecutado el código, se puede relanzar con ctrl+b